# how to do rails3 conditional caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, conditional-statements

I have a Rails3 application with Article model.

When admins are logged in, they can view articles that are "not authorized" by simply going to the article/show method:

```
if !@article.is_authorized and !user_signed_in?
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

I would like to cache articles from the moment they are authorized. How do I prevent them from being cached while the admins are reviewing them?

How can I place a code like the following in the action?

```
if @article.is_authorized
  cache_action
  or cache_fragment
  or whatever
```

Comment: you should cache the action and check auth in before_filter

Comment: is there such thing as conditional caching? can I choose whether to cache the action or not, based on an if-condition inside a before_filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As stated in the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching), you can pass a Proc:

```
caches_action :foo, if: lambda { your_condition_here }
```

Comment: The referenced 'doc' has been updated and no longer explains this.
Here is API documentation for it:
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/Caching/Actions